# adding functionality to programmatically created UIButtons

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I am trying to add functionality to dynamically created buttons.  I have created buttons with functionality before but never programatically.  Here is my code.

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil
        {
            print("error")
        }
        else
        {
            if let content = data
            {
                do
                {
                    //download JSON data from php page, display data
                    let SongArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! [[String]]
                    print(SongArray)

                    //Make buttons with JSON array
                    var buttonY:  CGFloat = 20
                    for song in SongArray {
                        let songButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: buttonY, width: 250, height: 30))
                        buttonY = buttonY + 50 // 50px spacing

                        songButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10  //Edge formatting for buttons

                        songButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray //Color for buttons

                        songButton.setTitle("\(song[0])", for: UIControlState.normal) //button title

                        songButton.titleLabel?.text = "\(song[0])"

                        songButton.addTarget(self,action: #selector(self.songButtonPressed(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.view.addSubview(songButton)  // adds buttons to view
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch
                {

                }
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()

}

 } //close viewDidLoad
 func songButtonPressed(_ sender:UIButton) { // function for buttons

if sender.titleLabel?.text == "\("Song[0]")" {
    print("So far so good!!")
}
 }
```

What I ideally want to do is use the function SongButtonPressed to run when any of the buttons are pressed, so far the app just crashes when I click on a button, though they appear just fine.  How can I use a function to add functionality to these buttons dynamically

Comment: Crash with what error?

Comment: If you want `SongButtonPressed` to run, use it as the selector.

Comment: 'libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException'

Comment: I believe this means there is no functionality associated with the button that was pressed.

Comment: Phillip could you show me what you mean? I am not familiar with this kind of functionality

Comment: I noticed you changed the button name. Also noticed you no longer have a nested function. Was that because of my "style" comment in my answer? If my full answer doesn't work, or more, doesn't at all answer your question... I'll remove/delete it. But consider your question... what's up? Ah, never mind. Down voted. Answer deleted. Jeez.

Comment: In case if someone thinks I just did a personal down vote, consider this: the original question had a nested function declared in viewDidLoad. It no longer does. I'm not sure how to flag this post but it deserves it. Seems someone is using our answers to edit the OP, which at first exhibited a lack of experience suited for this site.

Comment: I was asked by someone else who was helping me and no offense but their answer was more helpful, thanks for the personal down vote though

Answer (score 0):

Try by replacing the following line:
function name must be present in Selector attribute

SongButton.addTarget(self,action: #selector(self.SongButtonPressed(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

And most important function SongButtonPressed must be outside viewDidLoad

Comment: throws an error on that line, says 'Cannot convert value of type '(UIbutton) -> ()' to expected argument type 'String'

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the `UIKit` framework, so you can use the `.isHidden` method or `.isEnabled`

The hidden method with hide the button and the enabled method will have the button appear but the user will not be able to press the button.

To use the method write the following code.

```
Button.isHidden = true
```

Or

```
Button.is enabled = false
```

But if you use these methods you need to have a button that will do the opposite (set it to true if it is false or false if it is true) so that the button can be used again.